# IOError: connect: no such file or directory (ENOENT) at VSCode startup

Tags: visual-studio-code, julia

I use VSCode on Win10 with Julia 1.10. Every time I start up VSCode from scratch, before I do anything, I get the following error in the REPL. I’ve had it for a few days but I have no idea what I did to trigger it. How can I make it go away?

```
 *  History restored 

ERROR: LoadError: IOError: connect: no such file or directory (ENOENT)
Stacktrace:
 [1] wait_connected(x::Base.PipeEndpoint)
   @ Sockets C:\Users\TGebbels\AppData\Local\Programs\Julia-1.10.0\share\julia\stdlib\v1.10\Sockets\src\Sockets.jl:528
 [2] connect
   @ C:\Users\TGebbels\AppData\Local\Programs\Julia-1.10.0\share\julia\stdlib\v1.10\Sockets\src\Sockets.jl:563 [inlined]
 [3] connect
   @ C:\Users\TGebbels\AppData\Local\Programs\Julia-1.10.0\share\julia\stdlib\v1.10\Sockets\src\PipeServer.jl:103 [inlined]
 [4] serve(args::String; is_dev::Bool, crashreporting_pipename::String)
   @ VSCodeServer c:\Users\TGebbels\.vscode\extensions\julialang.language-julia-1.66.2\scripts\packages\VSCodeServer\src\VSCodeServer.jl:110
 [5] top-level scope
   @ c:\Users\TGebbels\.vscode\extensions\julialang.language-julia-1.66.2\scripts\terminalserver\terminalserver.jl:39
in expression starting at c:\Users\TGebbels\.vscode\extensions\julialang.language-julia-1.66.2\scripts\terminalserver\terminalserver.jl:14
julia>
```

Thanks!

Comment: report the bug to https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=julialang.language-julia

Comment: [Potentially related GH issues](https://github.com/julia-vscode/julia-vscode/issues?q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen+IOError%3A+connect%3A+no+such+file+or+directory+%28ENOENT%29)